# Can you let users with low rep to see a question/answer source?

Tags: feature-request

Many newbies ( rep 1 - 50 ) do not format their questions properly.

In many cases I could have made sense of their questions if allowed to view the question source ( I understand that I need to work more on my rep for actual editing ).

What's really frustrating, once somebody does make edits to their questions I can see the source for all question revisions.  So, it's not that system totally prevents the source peeking, only it prevents from peeking at newly created question source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the Edited "xx hours ago" and see all the revisions.  <strike>What are you proposing beyond that?</strike> Currently, as it stands, you cannot see the source until at least one edit is made if you are a low rep user.

After Brandon's comment, I see how this would be useful now. You got my support on this feature request. I need more coffee today.

Comment: There is no `Edited xx hours ago` link on a new question.

Comment: That is because there is no edits. You are seeing the orginal question.

Comment: I guess I don't completely understand what is in the original source that helps understand the question any more.

Comment: @Troggy: That's his issue; he wants to be able to view source on a question which has no edits yet.

Comment: @Troggy, a few times I've come across code that was just mashed together in the question view. If you viewed the source, you could see the code properly spaced out, it just hadn't been indented.

Comment: @Absinthe. Thanks for clarification. Who says absinthe destroys brain cells? :)

Comment: @Brandon: Ok, that is a good example. I see what the OP means now.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm trying to prove him right ... :)

Comment: need ... more.... coffee.

Comment: Troggy, try absinthe. It's practically the weekend!

Comment: Thanksgiving with Absinthe?  That'd make for an interesting family get together ... I'll stick with beer thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most user friendly method, but if you really care that much you can just go directly to the url.

For instance, this question has no edits, but if I were to replace the Id, I can access the revision history.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/30951/list

Comment: +1 for hearing my problem and a work-around. The solution would be more `obvious` with a link under question tags.  Just replace `edit` with `source` for users with low rep.